# How does modulus and rand() work?

Tags: c++, random

So, I've been nuts on this.

rand() % 6 will always produce a result between 0-5.

However when I need between, let's say 6-12.

Should I have rand() % 6 + 6

```
0+6 = 6.
1+6 = 7.
...
5+6 = 11. ???
```

So do I need to + 7 If I want the interval 6-12? But then, 0+7 =7. When will it randomize 6?

What am I missing here? Which one is the correct way to have a randomized number between 6 and 12? And why? It seems like I am missing something here.

Comment: Do you have two hands nearby? Count on your fingers, how many numbers are there between 6 and 12? What do you think you need for the `%` operator?

Comment: Sure Daniel, mock me all you want, however I was trying the "algoritm" provided by another SO question which is rand()%(max-min)+min;

Correct me If I am wrong, 12-6 = 6. min value is 6. So rand() % 6 + 6. That's why I am confused.

Comment: @John: It's a light-hearted way to tell you miss-counted it. You want seven different values, the argument you put on the right of `%` is how many different values you want to get. The algorithm you now mentioned is for a half-open interval (`[min, max)`); there are a few reasons to never use that (regarding both `rand()` and `%`); see Shafik's answer for the proper way to do it. Whoever told you to use `%` to generate random numbers within a range is probably too clueless to be instructing anyone. If it's a professor, feel free to send him the link to this question, we will straight him up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If *C++11* is an option then you should use the [random header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) and [uniform_int_distrubution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). As James pointed out in the comments using *rand* and `%` has a lot of issues including a biased distribution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;

    std::mt19937 e2(rd());

    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(6, 12);

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
            std::cout << dist(e2) << ", " ;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl ;
}
```

if you have to use [rand](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) then this should do:

```
rand() % 7 + 6
```

**Update**

A better method using `rand` would be as follows:

```
6 + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (12 - 6 + 1) + 1)
```

I obtained this from the *C FAQ* and it is explained [How can I get random integers in a certain range?](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html) question.

**Update 2**

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_random/tutorial.html) is also an option:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::random::mt19937 gen;
  boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(6, 12);

  for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
    std::cout << dist(gen) << ", ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl ;
}
```

Comment: @ktodisco: It's [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) again, better to just give the answer he needs instead of what he asked for.

Comment: @DanielKO I think a better answer would explain the solution to the problem specifically being asked, and then give the advice of a better solution.  It appears this answer has been edited to do so, though without explaining the former...

Answer (score 5):

You need rand() % 7 + 6.

Lowest number from rand() %7: 0.
Highest number from rand() %7: 6.

0 + 6 = 6.
6 + 6 = 12.

Answer (score 4):

The modulus operation `a % b` computes the remainder of the division `a / b`. Obviously the remainder of a division must be less than `b` and if `a` is a random positive integer then `a%b` is a random integer in the range 0 .. (b-1)

---

In the comments you mention:

> rand()%(max-min)+min

This algorithm produces values in the half-open range [min, max). (That is, max is outside the range, and simply denotes the boundary. Since we're talking about ranges of integers this range is equivalent to the closed range [min, max-1].)

When you write '0 - 5' or '6 - 12' those are closed ranges. To use the above equation you have to use the values that denote the equivalent half open range: [0, 6) or [6, 13).

```
rand() % (6-0) + 0

rand() % (13-6) + 6
```

Note that `rand() % (max-min) + min` is just a generalization of the rule you've apparently already learned: that `rand() % n` produces values in the range 0 - (n-1). The equivalent half-open range is [0, n), and `rand() % n` == `rand() % (n-0) + 0`.

So the lesson is: don't confuse half-open ranges for closed ranges.

---

A second lesson is that this shows another way in which `<random>` is easier to use than `rand()` and manually computing your own distributions. The built-in `uniform_int_distribution` allows you to directly state the desired, inclusive range. If you want the range 0 - 5 you say `uniform_int_distibution<>(0, 5)`, and if you want the range 6 - 12 then you say `uniform_int_distribution<>(6, 12)`.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::default_random_engine eng;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(6, 12);

  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    std::cout << dist(eng) << " ";
}
```

`rand()%7+6` is more terse, but that doesn't mean it is easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of concepts here.

First, there's the range: `[` denotes inclusive. `)` denotes exclusive.

The modulus operator % n produces `[0,n)` - 0,..n-1

When you add a value to that result, you're adding the same value to both ends of the ranges:

`%n + 6 = [n,n+6)`

Now, if n is 6, as it in in your case, your output will be `[0,6)`

`%6 + 6 = [6,12)`

Now what you want is `[6,13)`

Subtract 6 from that:

`[0,7) + 6 => n%7 + 6`

Second, there is the matter of using rand(). It depends on whether you really care if your data is random or not. If you do really care that it is random, I highly suggest watching Stefan T Lavalej's talk on [the pitfalls of using rand()](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) at Going Native 2013 this year. He also goes into what you should use.

If the randomness of rand() doesn't matter to you, then by all means use it.