# Random numbers in a range and matching pairs

Tags: c++, random

I have to generate a pair of random integers between 1-50. I then need to have my program generate five other numbers with the same range as the two random integers. I know how to generate the first pair but Iam having trouble creating the generation for the other 5. This is C++ by the way.

Comment: Do you have code for the first part? where did you get stuck on the second part? Show us some code.

Comment: This previous thread [How does modulus and rand() work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553265/how-does-modulus-and-rand-work) covers both options for C++ and C++11. Make the code modular and once you generate the first range then use the same code to generate the next range. In C++11 it is much simpler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ random float number generation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686353/c-random-float-number-generation)

Comment: @Caesar   #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1
    int num2
    rand()%50=num1;
    rand()%50=num2;      return 0;
} sorry i dont know how to write organized code on here

Comment: @user2980422 if you are going to add code to your question, the comments is not the right place. Edit your question and add your code there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I understand your problem, the following approach works for me.

Note that the 5 numbers will have the same absolute difference given by delta:

```
int delta = abs(pairOne.x - pairOne.y);
```

but you didn't mention whether or not x > y or y > x was a constraint (a simple modification can enable this). The code simply finds random numbers with the guaranteed difference (delta) as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

struct RandPair {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    // A Mersenne Twister pseudo-random generator:
    typedef std::mt19937 CppRNG;

    // Seed the generator:
    uint32_t seed_val = 0;
    CppRNG RandomGenerator;
    RandomGenerator.seed(seed_val);

    int min = 1;
    int max = 50;

    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> uniformMinMax(min, max);

    RandPair pairOne;
    RandPair otherPairs[5];

    pairOne.x = uniformMinMax(RandomGenerator);
    pairOne.y = uniformMinMax(RandomGenerator);

    std::cout << pairOne.x << "; " << pairOne.y << std::endl;

    int delta = abs(pairOne.x - pairOne.y);

    int count = 0;
    while (count < 5) {
        int r1 = uniformMinMax(RandomGenerator);
        int r2 = uniformMinMax(RandomGenerator);
        if ( abs(r1 - r2) == delta && count < 5 ) {
            otherPairs[count].x = r1;
            otherPairs[count].y = r2;
            count++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        std::cout << "delta: " << delta << "; " << otherPairs[i].x << "; " << otherPairs[i].y << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I need 5 numbers with the same difference as r1 and r2

Comment: @user2980422, Ok if I understand what you want, the above edit works, check it out.

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: @Griwes, Oh yes, great point. See my edit above, thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

This solution requires `#include <random>` and a C++11 capable compiler.

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> r1(1, 50);
int first = r1(mt), second = r1(mt);
if (first > second) std::swap(first, second);
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> r2(first, second);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    std::cout << r2(mt) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int a, b, low, high;

a = rand()%50 + 1;
b = rand()%50 + 1;

low = min(a,b);
high = max(a,b);

int ar[5];
int range = high-low+1;
for(int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
    ar[i] = rand()%(range) + low;
}
```

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work:

```
void printRandomNumbers( int low, int high )
{
    // Seed the random number generator.
    srand( time(0) )

    // Generate 2 random numbers between low and high (inlcusive).
    int a = ( rand() % ( high-low ) ) + ( low + 1 );
    int b = ( rand() % ( high-low ) ) + ( low + 1 );

    // Find a new low and new high.
    if ( a <= b )
    {
        low = a;
        high = b;
    } else {
        high = a;
        low = b;
    }

    printf("The new low is: %d\nThe new high is: %d\n", low, high);

    // Print 5 numbers inside the new range.
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", rand() % ( high-low ) + ( low + 1 ) );
    }    
}

int main()
{
    printRandomNumbers(0, 100);
}
```

If you don't want repeating numbers you're going to need to keep track of the output. Simplest way is using a basic c array[].

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: @Griwes Yes clearly there are better random number generators. However rand() is still taught in first-year C-programming classes for simplicity and the asker used it in his example code.

Comment: The fact it's still taught (or the fact that "first year C programming" is a thing, IDK) is absurd. And since OP *used* rand, not asked for it, you can just tell him "your way is wrong, consider this one". Proper answer on SO (which is not really meant to solve homeworks) should not include `rand()`. Even in pre-11 C++, there's Boost.Random, so there's always a better way than `rand`.