# rand() not working, gives me a number outside of the specified max and minimum

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, random

So I'm making a game were you're the boss an your hiring employees, I've used `rand` before but for some reason it's not working now:

Code generating the random number:

```
class employee
{

public:

int getSkills(int askingPrice)

    {
        srand((unsigned)time(0));

        switch(askingPrice)
        {
        case 1: //point of this is so if askingPrice is from 1 to 5 it will execute the same code
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:

            skills = rand() % 5 + 1;

        }
        return skills;
    }
    int returnSkills()
    {
        return skills;
    }

    int getPaid(int askingPrice)
    {
        srand((unsigned)time(0));
        switch(askingPrice)
        {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:


            paid = rand() % 5 + 1;

        }
        return paid;
    }
    int returnPaid()
    {
        return paid;
    }

    int getHappy(int askingPrice)
    {
        srand((unsigned)time(0));
        switch(askingPrice)
        {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:


            happy = rand() % 5 + 1;

        }
        return happy;
    }
    int returnHappy()
    {
        return happy;
    }
private:
    int skills, paid, happy;
};
```

Code displaying the random number:

```
std::cout <<"Your first employee is: " << one.returnPaid() << " salary, " <<             one.returnSkills() << " skilled @ his job, " << one.returnHappy() << " happy with his job";
```

and for some reason it displays as this:

```
Your first employee is: -858993460 salary, 3 killed @ his job, 3 happy with his job
```

Why am I getting a negative number for the salary but not anything else?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Your code is very difficult to read with pointless constructs such as these `switch` statements.

Comment: You should probably only be calling `srand` once in your entire program, and definitely not right before you call `rand` each time.

Comment: Since this is tagged C++11 you should [not be using rand anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19553318/1708801).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `one.returnPaid()`, `one.paid` is not yet initialized, because `one.getPaid()` (the only function where `one.paid` will receive a value) has not been called yet.

Comment: After you fix that, take the srand()s outside of the loop. If you call srand() more than once, you're not getting ramdom numbers, just a hash function of the time.