# Function for generate random number, not so random

Tags: c++, random

I write a function to generate random number, I call this function `every 10 mS`.

What I get is surprising, my number generate are a sequence of 3 ( 0,3,6,9,12,...)

Here's my function :

```
int utilitaireUDP::genereNombreAleatoire(int a, int b){
    int nombre_aleatoire = 0; //Sert a remplir la structure
    srand(time(NULL)); // initialisation de rand
    nombre_aleatoire = rand()%(b-a) +a;;
    return nombre_aleatoire;
}
```

Do I forget something ? Is the problem linked to my CPU ( because random number are generate from my internal clock ) ?

EDIT :
Thanks everyone !

I use this post to add something, I've got this function :

```
bool utilitaireUDP::genererBooleen(){
    if (genereNombreAleatoire(0,1) == 0){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this generate me only true, but I put the srand in my main now ... And it works perfectly for int ...

Comment: Have you tried using [the random header](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19553318/1708801)?

Comment: Seed only 1 time in your application. Never ever seed in a loop.

Comment: What are you passing as `a` and `b`?

Comment: @drescherjm Hooo Ok I'll try this.

Comment: This is silly-mistake #1 related to `rand` with approx. 1 million questions per week. Only `srand` once, not every time.

Comment: Be aware `rand` is usually not a high quality generator. If you have C++11 there are many better ones included.

Comment: BTW, you may use `std::uniform_int_distribution<>` in C++11.

Comment: It's not finish yet guys !

Comment: I think all the explanations you need can be found here: [how to generate different random number in a loop in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926622/how-to-generate-different-random-number-in-a-loop-in-c). It was right of findable from the **Related** section at the right. Pleas do a bit more research efforts before asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's rarely useful to call `srand` more than once during a run of a program; in particular, **don't try calling `srand` before each call to `rand`**, in an attempt to get *"really random"* numbers.

Remove `srand(time(NULL));` from your function and place it at program start up so that it called only once.