# Is there a random function that generates numbers between 0 and 1

Tags: c++

I have seen the use of **math.random()** in JavaScript to pick a random number between 0 and 1. Is this function also available in C++, or it is only included in Java and newer languages?

Comment: It does not really make sense to compare languages like this, in C++ you have a few choices as my [answer here lists](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19553318/1708801) basically `random header`, `boost` and `rand()`

Comment: I have not coded in C++ in ages. Isn't it rand?

Comment: The C++ standard library have many [functions and classes for pseudo-random number generation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: I know about the rand but what i am asking i sdoes math.random(); works in c++ or not.

Comment: Did you try? You would know the answer.

Comment: Java is not Javascript, in case your formulation implied that they were similar or related languages (which they aren't)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the `rand()` function from `<cstdlib>` library, which returns a number between 0 and `RAND_MAX`. If you want a number between 0 and 1, you have to do a workaround with casts and divisions:

```
double X = ((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX);
```

This is a practical example, putting the previous code inside a function:

```
#include <cstdlib> //  srand, rand
#include <ctime> // time
#include <iostream> //std::cout

double random01()
{
     return ((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX);
}

int main()
{

    srand(time(0)); // Remember to generate a seed for srand

    for(int i=0; i< 100; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << random01()  << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the random number generator function in C++, you need to include the  header.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int randomInteger = rand();
    cout << randomInteger << endl;


}
```

If you want to produce numbers in a specific range, you can use the modulo operator. It's not the best way to generate a range but it's the simplest. If we use rand() % n we generate a number from 0 to n-1. By adding an offset to the result we can produce a range that is not zero based. The following code will produce 20 random numbers from 1 to 10:

```
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    int random_integer; 
    for(int index=0; index<20; index++){ 
    random_integer = (rand()%10)+1; 
    cout << random_integer << endl; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the C++ library has a substantial numerics library, described in section 26 of the C++11. Specifically, the random number generation classes are described in section 26.5.

Since your question was only whether this functionality is "available in C++", the answer would be "yes".

You should be able to find plenty of examples of using the `std::random_device` class, and other classes from the random number generation library, by searching the Intertubes.

Answer (score 0):

```
int randomNumber = rand()%100; // for 0 to 99
```